# An image processing algorithm that can convert hand written formulae to LaTeX

Tags: equations

I have witnessed first hand the beautiful math typesetting LaTeX can produce and also the enormous effort that goes into writing formulae in LateX. So I was wondering that an image processing software that can convert photographs of hand written formulae on paper to LateX would be a tremendous time saver for the  LateX community.

What do you all think? Since I am  relatively new to LateX (couple of years), I wanted your feedback on how useful such a tool will be in your research or design projects.  Thanks.

Comment: Hi and welcome, we recently had this topic in our chat room. Please have a look at the [transcript](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/17924751#17924751).

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the Inlage editor. Sadly it doesen't support Linux.

Answer (score 0):

While this does not really fit your requirement of *"converting a photograph"*, it might still be useful for some people. There is a free iOS App called "[MyScript MathPad](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/myscript-mathpad-handwriting/id674996719?mt=8)" which lets you enter formulas using your finger or a stylus, and generates LaTeX code for them. However, I don't know what kind of algorithm they are using.